# type is invalid -- expected a string but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to use react-bootstrap table 2 and I would like to do column span.

Here my example,

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.timesheets} >
    <TableHeaderColumn row="0" dataField='empid'>Field B</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row="0" dataField='tdate'>Field C</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row="0" colSpan="2">In</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row="1">Time</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row="1">Date</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

I got this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

At the first step, `this.state.timesheets` would be nothing, so I thought because of this and I added one attribute `noDataIndication="Table is Empty"`. but this error is still happening.

Please help.

Comment: The question is how you are exporting and importing the component which is essentially the source of error I suppose. Will be needing more code in terms of that to more understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `TableHeaderColumn` will no longer support in react-bootstrap table 2.

[Documentation](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/blob/master/docs/migration.md)